# Setting up the equation for optimization problems

Tags: calculus, optimization

Micheal is on an island and needs to get to a bank on shore, He knows that he can swim at 3km/h and jog at 10km/h. The island is 1500m from the shore and the bank is 800m from the point on the shore closest to the island. Where on the shore should he land so he can minimize the time he takes in order to arrive at the bank before it closes?

First I drew a diagram to illustrate the situation (not to scale)
[image]
so the path on land can be represented by 800-x
and the path in water can be represented by √(1500² + x²)
combining these and the speed he can swim/jog, I end up with:
f(x) = 10(800-x) + 3(√(1500² + x²))

But this is marked wrong, so is there a better and correct way to approach this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your formulas $10(800-x)$ and $3\sqrt{1500^2+x^2}$ you assume that time is speed times distance. Actually, distance is speed times time, $d=vt$, so

$$t=\frac dv$$

So your time function should be

$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1500^2+x^2}}{3}+\frac{800-x}{10}$$

I changed the order of the terms to reflect the order that Michael does each kind of transportation--that meets my sense of style.